# LoadRunner: Automatic refresh of input data in parameter files

Tags: loadrunner

Does anyone know of a VuGen plugin that could automatically copy data from a .txt file without any manual intervention?
Tried searching on Internet , but  did not find any answers.

Regards,
Sutapa

Answer (score 0):

You can use your txt file as parameter file.
You just need to open the parameter list dialog, click on 'New', select Parameter type: File (default) and change the file path to your txt file. 
One more thing - you must insert as first row in your txt file - the parameter name (copied from VuGen's original file. For example: NewParam).